# TSQL Group By including all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I have a TSQL Query that does something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(s.Amount) as TotalSales, p.ProductName
FROM SALES s 
INNER JOIN Product p ON s.ProductID = p.ID
GROUP BY p.ProductName
```

The resulting output is

```
TotalSales  Product
-----------------------
123.45      Apples
234.56      Oranges
345.67      Grapes
```

What I would like to do is get ALL the products in the results, even the ones that have no sales.  I tried doing a LEFT JOIN on the product table, but that just confuses things.

So I would like my output to be something like this.

```
TotalSales  Product
-----------------------
123.45      Apples
234.56      Oranges
345.67      Grapes
0.0         Lemons
0.0         Grapefruit
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(s.Amount,0)) as TotalSales, p.ProductName
FROM SALES s 
RIGHT JOIN Product p ON s.ProductID = p.ID
GROUP BY p.ProductName
```

Comment: Using a RIGHT JOIN will turn up NULL `PRODUCT.PRODUCTNAME` records in the output.  The correct approach is to LEFT JOIN onto the optional table (`SALES` in this case).

Comment: By the way, try not to mix `LEFT JOIN` with `RIGHT JOIN` later on when this query evolved.  It WILL DRIVE YOU  NUTS!!! (see i am using all caps just thinking about it)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(s.Amount), 0) as TotalSales, p.ProductName
FROM Product p
LEFT JOIN SALES s ON s.ProductID = p.ID
GROUP BY p.ProductName
```

Comment: I think you need to wrap the SUM(s.Amount) in a coalesce to get the "0"

Answer (score 2):

With left join (more readeability):

```
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(s.Amount,0)) as TotalSales, p.ProductName
FROM Product p 
LEFT JOIN SALES s ON p.ProductID = s.ID
GROUP BY p.ProductName
```